# How to apply ImageMagick effect (selective blur) to all WordPress uploaded images automatically ? I have Imagick installed

Tags: wordpress, imagemagick, wordpress-theming, imagick

I don't really know how to apply php code to WordPress manually.
I have found some script but don't know where and how to put them.

`public Imagick::selectiveBlurImage ( float $radius , float $sigma , float $threshold [, int $channel = Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT ] ) : bool`

```
<?php
function selectiveBlurImage($imagePath, $radius, $sigma, $threshold, $channel) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->selectiveBlurImage($radius, $sigma, $threshold, $channel);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}

?>
```

> Source  [Imagick::selectiveBlurImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.selectiveblurimage.php)

And want to add it as this filter will act before finally uploading image. Found similar function at `wp-admin/includes/file.php`

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );

function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    $file['name'] = 'wordpress-is-awesome-' . $file['name'];
    return $file;
}
```

> Source [1st Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter) & [2nd Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload_prefilter/)

If there isn't any way to pre-apply filter effect then auto-apply effect after upload is welcome.

If there there is any WordPress Plug-in available to do that?

The effect will change [original photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z6H3.jpg) to [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lA2n.jpg)

> Effect Source  [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/toonify/index.php) with effect arguments:
> `-b 4 -t 10 -e none -q 0`

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377231/wordpress-blur-image-on-upload) ,but i am unaware of the file directory and process to add those code. It has some resize issue which in my case isn't. I want to apply this filter to any picture uploaded.

Comment: This isn't something you apply ta an image per say, but it is used before rendering the image on the front end. This goes where you're generating your image (eg: a post thumbnail). It's not possible to do it the way you want.

Comment: thank you for comment. if there's any other way to apply that effect, that will be okay. I just want to apply that effect permanently and automatically any how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress - Blur Image on Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377231/wordpress-blur-image-on-upload)

Comment: i don't know where and how to put codes. with modification... i need a elongated guide. please help

Comment: @RobertColumbia I am unaware of the file directory and process to add those code. that question has some resize issue which in my case isn't. I want to apply this filter to any picture uploaded.